# gcloud ssh with localhost:8080 for deeplearning-vm is not established

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, deep-learning, jupyter-lab

I have created an instance using deeplearning VM image. And established SSH, but while accessing the jupyter lab (using Google SDK CLI locally) at the localhost:8080 it returns an error

```
bind [127.0.0.11:8080: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8080
could not request local forwarding
```

[here is the screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIgdH.jpg)

PS: I have also tried using cloud shell, ended up with the same error.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!!

Comment: It simply means another process is using that port. Have you investigated the error message at least?

Comment: I have found a solution, gonna try that. Hopefully, that helps.